# which one is correct? 'to complete' or 'to completing'?

Tags: grammar, word-usage, sentence-structure

Which sentence is correct and why?

1. She will dedicate her life to completing a mission
2. She will dedicate her life to complete a mission

shouldn't (1) be  'in completing?'

Comment: Can you edit to explain two things? Why do you think (1) should be in not to? Which sentence do you think is correct, if any, and why? Then people can help you better.

Answer (score 1):

Sentence number 1 seems to be more correct to me. To answer your question, "in ___ing" is not usually used, at least not as often as "to ___ing," with one exception: when talking about succeeding at a specific action. For example, you would say

> I still can't believe she succeeded **in building** the tallest Jenga tower in the world.
>
> I can't believe she still won't admit **to liking** that guy.

[A potentially helpful website](https://www.espressoenglish.net/to-followed-by-ing/) for further reference and examples.

Comment: Thank you! suggested website explains exactly what I was looking for :)
It seems that I'll have to memorize these exceptions.

Answer (score 1):

The word "to" can have several slight difference in meaning. It can be a particle that's part of the full infinitive. It can be a preposition indicating destination, and it can be a preposition indicating purpose. For the preposition indicating destination, it requires a noun or noun-like word as an object, so the gerund "completing" works, but the infinitive "complete" does not. So "She will dedicate her life to completing a mission" works: completing a mission is the thing her life is being dedicated to.

The infinitive "complete" does, however, work as the object of "to" in the sense of a preposition indicating purpose. So if you wanted to say *why* she was dedicating her life, you can say "She will dedicate her life to complete a mission" to mean "The reason she will dedicate her life is because she wants to complete a mission."

If you had "She will dedicate her life in completing a mission", that means that the process of completing a mission will result in dedicating her life.